# Empty clause symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols

This is a very simple question. I was wondering if anybody might know of a way to generate the symbol for the empty clause in LaTeX (small, character-sized empty square). By ``empty clause" I am referring to the propositional / first-order logic symbol which denotes a clause that is unsatisfiable by default, and is the result of a refutation from a set of unsatisfiable clauses.

Comment: `\fbox{\phantom{x}}`? or `\begingroup\fboxsep1pt\fbox{\phantom{x}}\endgroup` perhaps. Admittedly, this is not a square. `\begingroup\fboxsep0pt\fbox{\phantom{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}}\endgroup`

Comment: Would you be OK with `amssymb`'s `\square`?

Comment: Yeah, \square worked somewhat better in terms of size requirements. Thanks!

Comment: @jfbu `\fboxsep=-0.5\fboxrule` is possibly better. And `\vrule height 1ex width 0pt \kern 1ex` for filling the box is more efficient than `\phantom{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}`

Comment: You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 14):

You have several options available. Some predefined squares or a hand-made one

```
\newcommand{\Hsquare}{%
  \text{\fboxsep=-.2pt\fbox{\rule{0pt}{1ex}\rule{1ex}{0pt}}}%
}
```

(requires `\usepackage{amsmath}`). Here's a table with some of the squares:

[image]

In the second column you find what package provides the symbol (next to `\Hsquare` I could have added `amsmath`, which is however not a font package). Note that you should say `\text{\Squarepipe}` if you decide for that symbol.

Answer (score 1):

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\littlesquare}{\scriptstyle{\square}}
\newcommand{\tinysquare}{\scriptscriptstyle{\square}}
```

usage as

```
square $\square$, littlesquare $\littlesquare$, and tinysquare $\tinysquare$
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). `amssymb` is needed for `\square`.